# Remove empty tags at XML using Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm giving some functionality to a servlet, one of the things I want to do is, when receiving the InputStream (which is basically a PDF document parsed into an XML format) set that data to a String object, then I try to delete all the empty tags, but I haven't got any good result so far:

This is the data the servlet is receiving

```html
    <form1>
        <GenInfo>
            <Section1>
                <EmployeeDet>
                    <Title>999990000</Title>
                    <Firstname>MIKE</Firstname>
                    <Surname>SPENCER</Surname>
                    <CoName/>
                    <EmpAdd>
                        <Address><Add1/><Add2/><Town/><County/><Pcode/></Address>
                    </EmpAdd>
                    <PosHeld>DEVELOPER</PosHeld>
                    <Email/>
                    <ConNo/>
                    <Nationality/>
                    <PPSNo/>
                    <EmpNo/>
                </EmployeeDet>
            </Section1>
        </GenInfo>
    </form1>
```

The final result should be looking like this:

```html
    <form1>
        <GenInfo>
            <Section1>
                <EmployeeDet>
                    <Title>999990000</Title>
                    <Firstname>MIKE</Firstname>
                    <Surname>SPENCER</Surname>
                    <PosHeld>DEVELOPER</PosHeld>
                </EmployeeDet>
            </Section1>
        </GenInfo>
    </form1>
```

My apologies if it is a repeated question but I did some research over similar posts and none of them could provide me the correct approach, that's why I am asking you in a separate post.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please explain the approaches you have already taken.

Comment: What API are you using to parse the XML? Parse the XML, and go through all elements. Delete elements that have no content, no children and no attributes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's `regex` way of doing what you're wanting.  I'm sure there are probably some "edge" cases that I'm not thinking of, but sometimes you can't tell when you use `regex`.  Also, a DOM parser is probably the best way to do this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] patterns = new String[] {
        // This will remove empty elements that look like <ElementName/>
        "\\s*<\\w+/>", 
        // This will remove empty elements that look like <ElementName></ElementName>
        "\\s*<\\w+></\\w+>", 
        // This will remove empty elements that look like 
        // <ElementName>
        // </ElementName>
        "\\s*<\\w+>\n*\\s*</\\w+>"
    };

    String xml = "    <form1>\n" +
                    "        <GenInfo>\n" +
                    "            <Section1>\n" +
                    "                <EmployeeDet>\n" +
                    "                    <Title>999990000</Title>\n" +
                    "                    <Firstname>MIKE</Firstname>\n" +
                    "                    <Surname>SPENCER</Surname>\n" +
                    "                    <CoName/>\n" +
                    "                    <EmpAdd>\n" +
                    "                        <Address><Add1/><Add2/><Town/><County/><Pcode/></Address>\n" +
                    "                    </EmpAdd>\n" +
                    "                    <PosHeld>DEVELOPER</PosHeld>\n" +
                    "                    <Email/>\n" +
                    "                    <ConNo/>\n" +
                    "                    <Nationality/>\n" +
                    "                    <PPSNo/>\n" +
                    "                    <EmpNo/>\n" +
                    "                </EmployeeDet>\n" +
                    "            </Section1>\n" +
                    "        </GenInfo>\n" +
                    "    </form1>";

    for (String pattern : patterns) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(xml);
        xml = matcher.replaceAll("");
    }

    System.out.println(xml);
}
```

Results:

```
    <form1>
        <GenInfo>
            <Section1>
                <EmployeeDet>
                    <Title>999990000</Title>
                    <Firstname>MIKE</Firstname>
                    <Surname>SPENCER</Surname>
                    <PosHeld>DEVELOPER</PosHeld>
                </EmployeeDet>
            </Section1>
        </GenInfo>
    </form1>
```

Comment: @JoseBerciano You're welcome... Kindly click the check mark to my answer so your question is solved and removed from the unanswered list.

Comment: it's failing if tag is  <abc:title/>.
Can you help me to find regex for it

Comment: Same problem here @Ramesh have you found a solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is iterate recursively over all the nodes. And once you've found a leaf, it's it's empty just remove it.

There is a very good example using DOM parser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524727/remove-empty-nodes-from-a-xml-recursively)