# Remove all occurance of a string with certain pattern

Tags: java, string, jackson

I want to exclude all empty element from a String containing an xml. By empty element I mean strings with this pattern: `<someStringWithRandomValue/>`.

I tried to do this directly during the serializaation by adding the following annotation to the variables

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

or

```
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

but this is not working. Is there any solution to remove all strings with this pattern from a string after the serialization?

Comment: Can you put a detailed elaboration of the input string what it contains, It will help in getting a quick solution.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577448/remove-empty-tags-at-xml-using-java